# Python global exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` globally, and deal with it nicely.  I don't want to encase my entire script in a huge try/except statement.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You could change `sys.excepthook` if you really don't want to use a `try/except`.

```
import sys
def my_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    if exctype == KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Handler code goes here"
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)
sys.excepthook = my_except_hook
```

Docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__excepthook__

Comment: Use `sys.__excepthook__` which contains the original value of `sys.excepthook` instead of manually saving it.

Comment: Great point; I didn't realize `sys.__excepthook__` would retain the old value.

Comment: Saving the old one and calling it has the advantage that several `excepthook`s can be chained.

Comment: Would this also catch the exceptions thrown by a thread spawned by the main thread?

Comment: @PankajParashar See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643327/sys-excepthook-and-threading) thread.

Comment: Will this prevent from crashing when unhandled exception occurs?

Comment: As-written, this only suppresses the interruption due to `KeyboardInterrupt`. All other exceptions will still result in the same behavior as though the `sys.excepthook` were not changed.

Comment: Another wrong accepted answer. See answer by @mouad for the right way to handle `KeyboardInterrupt`s.

Comment: I like @mouad's solution much better... but I absolutely love the fact that you can just go ahead and **do this** in Python.

Comment: This works in a script and in a Python console, but not IPython apparently.  Why?

Comment: This is also excellent for globally adding a helpful message when `ImportError` or a subclass like `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised, to explain how the user can install the relevant requirements, for example within your custom `excepthook` something like: `if issubclass(exctype, ImportError):` (newline) `print(f'Failed to import a required dependency:\n {exctype.__name__}: {value}\nEnsure your venv is activated and pip install the latest dev requirements as per the README')`

Answer (score 25):

If this is a script for execution on the command line, you can encapsulate your run-time logic in `main()`, call it in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` and wrap that.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Killed by user'
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This won't handle uncaught exceptions in other threads, besides your main thread. As multipleinterfaces suggested, sys.excepthook is the way to go

Comment: @OrlinGeorgiev [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643327/sys-excepthook-and-threading) thread says otherwise.

Comment: This also won't help you when the exception is raised somewhere up the call stack and you have exception handlers between there & the top level.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) like this:

```
import signal, time

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'I just clicked on CTRL-C '

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

print "waiting for 10 s"
time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
waiting for 10 s
^CI just clicked on CTRL-C
```

N.B: Don't mix the use of signal with threads.

Comment: Actually, catching the signal should be _the_ answer for this.

Comment: There is no problem with using signals in python threads. You just need to be aware of the fact, that you need to set the handler from the main threads and that it is always executed in the main thread. The default `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is also raised from a signal handler.

Answer (score 10):

Does your script have a function you call to start it?

```
main()
```

then just do:

```
try:
    main()
except:
    ...
```

If you don't have a `main` but just a huge script that runs line-by-line, then you should put it in a `main`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way to do this, apart from encasing your entire script in a `main()` function and surrounding that with a `try..except` block - which is pretty much the same:

```
def main():
    # Your script goes here
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # cleanup code here
        pass
```

Comment: The suggestion is valid, but it's incorrect that there is no other way, as demonstrated by other answers.