# How to disable stack trace in python

Tags: python, logging, stack-trace

I would like to disable the stack trace that is printed when there is an exception raised.

Comment: There are no security reasons for disabling the stack trace.

Comment: the reason is not so important so I removed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Global Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598053/python-global-exception-handling)

Comment: That doesn't solve what I'm worried about (you assuming it is beneficial for security).

Comment: This question is not about security

Comment: I get that, but you wouldn't be the first to ask a question based on a faulty premise and would benefit more from correcting that assumption.

Comment: Purely out of interest, what reason do you have?

Comment: I would like to remove stack trace information from the log on production environment

Answer (score 3):

Looking around I found the following solution / workaround:

sys.tracebacklimit = 0

Comment: Please dont. Having tracebacks is a GoodThing(tm). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598053/python-global-exception-handling and http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception for the right way to keep the traceback private.

Comment: What you actually want is a custom `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: bruno, can you add an example for the way you can have an exception being logged without the stacktrace? you are welcome to add this as an  answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the code calls the `logger.exception` method, the stack trace is automatically printed.
That's because the default value of the `exc_info` parameter of the `.exception` method is True.

See the source code:

```py
def exception(msg, *args, exc_info=True, **kwargs):
    """
    Log a message with severity 'ERROR' on the root logger, with exception
    information. If the logger has no handlers, basicConfig() is called to add
    a console handler with a pre-defined format.
    """
    error(msg, *args, exc_info=exc_info, **kwargs)
```

To prevent this, you can send `exc_info=False` to the  `.exception` method like this:

```py
  try:
      raise Exception("Huston we have a problem!")
  except Exception as ex:
      logger.exception(f"Looks like they have a problem: {ex}", exc_info=False)
```

While this seems like working, it is bad to force users to write `exc_info=False` each time they use that method. Therefore, in order to take this burden from the shoulders of the programmers, you can monkey patch the `.exception` method and make it act like a regular `.error` method like this:

```py
# somewhere in the start of your program
# money patch the .exception method
logger.exception = logger.error

  try:
      raise Exception("Huston we have a problem!")
  except Exception as ex:
      logger.exception(f"Looks like they have a problem: {ex}")
```