# Python logging.handlers.SocketHandler not broadcasting except in App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I'm trying to broadcast my error log with a SocketHandler, and it's working great if I put this in the main.py of my app engine project, but if I just write a simple stand alone python script and run it, it doesn't seem to successfully broadcast the logs.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

sh = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
rootLogger.addHandler(sh)

logging.info(['Test', 'This', 'List'])
logging.info(dict(Test = 'Blah', Test2 = 'Blah2', Test3 = dict(Test4 = 'Blah4')))
```

I'm at a loss as to how to go about debugging this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default level for logging is `WARNING`, so `INFO` messages will not be seen by default. You need a `rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to see `INFO` messages, for example, or set the level to `logging.DEBUG` to see all messages.

**Update:** It's hard to see how logging.error() would fail to output where logging.info() does, unless there is a filter involved or an error during the logging.error() call. Please post a runnable script which demonstrates the issue when run with the logging socket server [described in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network).

**Further update:** logging doesn't *automatically* capture exceptions. To log an exception, the usual thing for the developer to do is to use a `try: except:` block and to call `logging.exception(...)` in the exception handling code.

Comment: Well that was easy. I guess app engine is setting the log level to DEBUG by default. Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty related so I'm going to try to ask it here. If I set the debug level to DEBUG or ERROR and use isEnabledFor(logging.ERROR) I get true, but it's not sending errors. Info logs send, but if I intentionally add an error right after the logging configuration, it does not send.

Comment: I think I miss-communicated. My problem is it won't broadcast exceptions. If I take that example code and introduce an exception by changing the first logging.info line to loging.info, that exception is not broadcast.

Comment: So what I needed was global exception handling, which I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598053/python-global-exception-handling