# Python multiprocessing: how to exit cleanly after an error?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am writing some code that makes use of the `multiprocessing` module. However, since I am a newbie, what often happens is that some error pops up, putting a halt to the main application.

However, that applications' children still remain running, and I get a long, long list of running `pythonw` processes in my task manager list.

After an error occurs, what can I do to make sure all the child processes are killed as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two pieces to this puzzle.

1. How can I detect and kill all the child processes?
2. How can I make a best effort to ensure my code from part 1 is run whenever one process dies?

For part 1, you can use [`multiprocessing.active_children()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#miscellaneous) to get a list of all the active children and kill them with `Process.terminate()`. Note the use of `Process.terminate()` comes with the usual warnings.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name
    while True: pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()

    # At user input, terminate all processes.
    raw_input("Press Enter to terminate: ")
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
       p.terminate()
```

One solution to part 2 is to use `sys.excepthook`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598286/391161). Here is a combined example.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
import sys
from  time import sleep

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name
    while True: pass

def myexcepthook(exctype, value, traceback):
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
       p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

    # Sleep for a bit and then force an exception by doing something stupid.
    sleep(1)
    1 / 0
```

Comment: I suppose then, as an extension that I could have a try/except block. If an exception is caught, then I could run `for p in ... p.terminate()`, before printing the error that was caught?

Comment: @user89, Yes, that will work. I have just updated to show how to update the global exception handler for *uncaught* exceptions.