# Why do main- and child-process not exit after exception in main?

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
#coding=utf8
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import os 

def foo():
    print("foo")
    for i in range(11000):
        sleep(1)
        print("{}: {}".format(os.getpid(), i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=foo)
    #p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    print("parent: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    sleep(20)
    raise Exception("invalid")
```

An exception is raised in the main-process, but child- and main-process keep running. Why?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716951/python-multiprocessing-how-to-exit-cleanly-after-an-error

Comment: @Melvin actually, I know what to do to make the child process exit. I just want to know what happened when there's no daemon flag or excepthook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the MainProcess is shutting down, non-daemonic child processes are simply joined. This happens in `_exit_function()` which is registered with `atexit.register(_exit_function)`. You can look it up in `multiprocessing.util.py` if you are curious.

You can also insert `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)` before you start your process to see the log messages:

```
parent: 9670
foo
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
9675: 0
9675: 1
...
9675: 18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/...", line 26, in <module>
    raise Exception("invalid")
Exception: invalid
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process Process-1
9675: 19
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.It's really helpful to set the log level for the multiprocessing module