# Exception that emails stack trace when raised

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'd like to have an exception that always sends an email when raised. As for now, I was planning to put that code into `__init()`:

```
import sendmail
import configparser


def MailException(BaseException):
    """
    sends mail when initiated
    """
    def __init__(self, message, config=None):
        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        BaseException.__init__(message)

        if config is None:
            config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
            config.read('mail.ini')
            config = config['email']

        text = 'exception stack trace + message'

        sendmail.sendMail(text=text, config=config['email'], title='Alert')
```

I'd explicitly like to have the mail-sending here, instead of in every except-block I create. Hence I wonder how to get the stack trace, the code has to be compatible with Python 2.7.

The only thing I could find was `traceback`, but that apparently only works within the `except:` realm - or is there a way to implement it within the Exception class? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that (per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException)) you shouldn't subclass `BaseException`.

Secondly, rather than implement that logic in the exception itself you could define a new [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) (see e.g. [Python Global Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6598053/3001761)), then you get access to the full traceback:

```
import sys


class MailException(Exception):
    pass


def mailing_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    if exctype == MailException:
        ...  # do your thing here
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = mailing_except_hook
```