# Raise exception as callback

Tags: python, python-2.7

In some exception handling code, I'd like to perform an emergency shutdown operation and then re-raise the exception. I am using an asynchronous programming model (Twisted), and I would like to re-raise the exception in the emergency shutdown's callback.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
except Exception as e:
    d = emergencyStop()
    d.addCallback(partial(raiseExn, e))
```

I could define my own `raiseExn` function:

```
def raiseExn(e):
    raise e
```

But it seems silly to add three or four lines to every place I want to use this code. I expect that the `raise` keyword probably calls a function somewhere in the Python standard library and it would be better to use that. But what is that function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Global Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598053/python-global-exception-handling)

Comment: Specifically, see the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`generator.throw`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=throw#generator.throw) for this purpose. The example looks like

```
except Exception as e:
    d = emergencyStop()
    d.addCallback(lambda: (_ for _ in ()).throw(e)))
```