# sys.excepthook -vs- handled exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I noticed that exceptions that are handled do not result in a call to `sys.excepthook`... which makes sense in retrospect.

But, how *do* I log or otherwise customize the way that *handled* exceptions are dealt with? When this code executes...

```
try:
    1/0
except:
    pass
```

I would like to be able to log the fact that a `ZeroDivisionError` was handled.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Exception` and print info about it or log that with a logging call of your own:

```
try:
  1/0
except Exception, e:
  print("a {0} was not raised".format(e.__class__.__name__))
  # or logging.yourLogger(e.__class__.__name__)
  pass
```

Result:

```
a ZeroDivisionError was not raised
```

If you were looking for some kind of Global Exception Handling, that is probably not trivial or [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598053/python-global-exception-handling) without enclosing everything in `try/except`.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I was looking for a global solution. Bummer. I'm dealing with a gigantic codebase where `try/except` is abused all over the place. The root cause is often silenced in places where it should not be. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It looks like it might be possible with https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace ...maybe just intercept 'exception'? I'll post here if results are interesting.