# Any way for Python to return from a function mid-body without an explicit return?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is a condensed version of the code I'm dealing with:

```
def main():
    foo()
    print("Only this line will get printed")

def foo():
    bar()
    print("This line is never reached")

main()
```

The output of this program is "Only this line will get printed", and I cannot figure out why. Effectively, it's acting as if there's a return statement at or right after the line where `bar()` gets called.

My only guess was that `bar()` raises an exception, but I surrounded it with a blank `try/catch` block and it's not catching anything.

Any idea what could be happening here?

P.S. this is running inside a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: "NameError: bar is not defined"

Comment: Highly dependent on what `bar()` looks like. We can;t reproduce from this sample code. (See: [mcve])

Comment: It sounds like the code is calling `sys.exit()`.

Comment: It could be an endless loop, a request that doesn't resolve or any type of code that never resolves

Comment: Please add the code contained within the `bar` function. If there is no `bar` function then that's the problem....

Comment: What do you mean by "blank `try`/`catch`"?

Comment: @JohnGordon it can't be `sys.exit()` inside `bar()` since then "Only this line will get printed" would not.

Comment: @G.Anderson `bar()` is a gateway to an entire call tree containing massive amounts of code. It would take me days just to read all of it. The reason I'm posting this question is because I can't see a reason why _anything_ that could possibly happen inside `bar()` would cause this problem. Generally, either `bar()` terminates the program somehow (in which nothing will get printed) or it raises an exception (in which case again nothing will get printed) or it blocks forever (same result). Either way, nothing gets printed.

Comment: My guess is that `foo()` is being overwritten by another definition somewhere later in the code, that doesn't have the `print`.  The way to find out what's actually going on here is to run the code in a debugger.

Comment: Are you asking *"how could code possibly have this behaviour?"* or are you asking *"what is the most likely explanation?"* - the former is maybe a little bit too broad (I'm not sure), the latter is probably subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways I can think of that a program might have this behaviour, but all of them seem *really* unlikely. It is hard to imagine that this could happen unless someone did it intentionally as a prank, or as the solution to an abstract puzzle/challenge, like *"can you make a program do this?"*.

There is certainly no sensible way that calling `bar` could cause `foo` to return immediately. If `bar` raises an exception, `foo` would stop before printing, but so would `main` since it has no `try`/`except` block. There are some things you can do with `sys.excepthook` to set a [global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6598053/12299000), which could explain why `bar` is able to stop `foo` without you seeing a stack trace, but the exception handler would not cause `main` to continue where `foo` left off.

Well, here is my solution to the puzzle, which *I hope* is not what your program is actually doing:

```py
def bar():
    # we will change which function `print` refers to
    global print

    # keep a reference to the built-in `print` function
    old_print = print

    # define a function which ignores its argument, then restores the old `print` function
    def ignore_one_print(s):
        global print
        print = old_print

    # change `print` to be the function we just defined
    print = ignore_one_print
```

When combined with your code, it outputs:

```
Only this line will get printed
```