# Grab any exception in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, logging, pyqt4

I've created an GUI app in PyQt, which I want to share with many people. Sometimes I get unexpected exceptions and I take it for granted - after every exception I improve my code and it gets better and better.

I use a logger for recording these exceptions and special hook for PyQt silenced exceptions. My code looks like this:

**Logger**

```
def setLogger(level=logging.DEBUG,
              name="my_logger",
              file=join("src", "log.out")):

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    # console logger
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_lvl = logging.DEBUG
    ch.setLevel(console_lvl)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    #file logger    
    fh = logging.FileHandler(file)
    fh.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s :: %(name)s - %(message)s',
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```

**2 typical classes in GUI**

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = setLogger(name='main_window')
        [...]

class UploadDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self):
    self.logger = setLogger(name='upload_dialog')
    [...]
```

and so on
PyQt has its silenced exceptions - exception occurs but program keeps running. I use the special hook for this situation (have seen it somewhere, this is not my code)

```
import sys
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)
```

And now I want to grab any exception, so the users of my program in case of any crash could just send me their **log.out** and I would see the full log.

I've started from something like this.

```
try:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except Exception:
    logger.exception("MainWindow exception")
```

I worked well, until an exception was raised inside **UploadDialog**. Nothing was 'recorded'. So I just did:

```
#inside MainWindow class
def runDialog(self):
    try:
        dialog = UploadDialog()
        dialog.exec_()
    except Exception:
        self.logger.exception("Dialog exception")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Again, everything was OK, until an exception was rised inside **WorkThread** (Inherited from QThread class for background upload). And again.

```
#inside UploadDialog
def upload(self):
    # initialized as self.task = WorkThread()
    try:
        self.task.start()
    except Exception:
        self.logger.exception("Exception in WorkThread")
```

And then an exception was raised not after start of WorkThread but when initializing, so

```
class UploadDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.task = WorkThread()
        except Exception:
            self.logger.exception("Exception in WorkThread")
```

And here I just took my head and screamed to myself - "STOP IT. YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG. It's not pythonic, it's dirty, it makes my eyes bleed".

So, I'm asking - is there any elegant and pythonic way to grab ABSOLUTELY any exception, raised in PyQt app with one `try...except` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of using an excepthook is so you can monitor **all** exceptions that are raised by your program, and handle them centrally.

So you should get rid of most of those `try/except` blocks, and log the exceptions inside the excepthook function. I say "most", because you may be affected by [bug 1230540](http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540), where `sys.excepthook` is not called correctly outside of the main thread. See the tracker thread for some workarounds for that, or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622038/984421).

Comment: Tried raising exceptions in ```QThread``` - everything works OK, so I don't need any addinional hack and I've completely removed all ```try...except``` and feel much happier)

Comment: Could you show what you finally added to grab the exceptions?