# How can I get PyQT to display an error mesage in case of exception?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

Using Python 3.7 and PyQT 5.14, I sometimes get an error but rather than having an exception or a message, I only get an exit code such as this one : `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` and it does not make debugging a very easy task.

I tried to to catch an exception but it does not seem to work. Event went as far as to try and catch everything :

```
try:
    app.exec_()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But the try / except is completely ignored.

How can I get error messages that are easy to understand ?

In this case, the error is due to me trying to read a value that does not exist of a QTextEdit class. But it's not an information I am going to get from that code.

If it can help, I am using the latest version of PyCharm ( the JetBrains IDE )

Comment: Run the application in the terminal / CMD and get a specific error.

Comment: thanks for the info, it does indeed work. Do you know how to intercept the exceptions ? I need them to put them into logs. Else it is going to be almost impossible to understand why the users of my program are not able to use it.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgitb.html

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a precious tool i knew nothing about ^^

Comment: please write this as an answer that I may vote and accept it ^^

Comment: There are already answers about this, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819330/catching-exceptions-raised-in-qapplication

Comment: yep, just found it, did not use the correct keywords when looking for answers and ended up not seeing it