# 'sys.excepthook' and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, sys

I'm trying to use a custom sys.excepthook with the multiprocessing library to handle exceptions on all threads. I know there's an [outstanding bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540) with python that prevents this from working correctly with the Threading library, and testing shows that this also affects multiprocessing.

The Python bug and [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643327/sys-excepthook-and-threading) that led me to it both have workarounds for the Threading library, but nothing for multiprocessing. I have tried to adapt the workaround for use with multiprocessing, but the exception is still thrown as usual.

```
def install_thread_excepthook():
    import sys
    start_old = multiprocessing.Process.start
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            start_old(*args, **kwargs)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
    multiprocessing.Process.start = run
```

How do I make sys.excepthook work properly with multiprocessing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sys.excepthook on multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815850/python-sys-excepthook-on-multiprocess)