# Python sys.excepthook on multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to set custom `sys.excepthook` on multiprocess.
but it does not work.

In below code, I have expected that to print `This is my traceback function:` string as a prefix of error message, but it doesn't.

code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import traceback
import logging
import sys

def excepthook(etype, evalue, traceback):
    traceback_strs = traceback.format_exception_only(etype, evalue)
    exception_str = "This is my traceback function:" + "\r\n".join(traceback_strs)
    print("ExceptHook")
    print(exception_str)


def subprocess_main():
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    time.sleep(3)
    raise Exception("HelloWorld")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=subprocess_main)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Why it does not work?

OS:Windows10
Python: 3.6.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sys.excepthook` is called when there is an uncaught exception, but `Process` [has exception handler routine](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L270-L278), which consumed the exception before your hook.

If you still want custom exception handling, you may overriden `Process.run` method:

```
class MyProcess(Process):

    def run(self):
        try:
            super().run()
        except Exception:
            excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
```

ps: argument `traceback` of your original function `excepthook` shadowed module object `traceback`, which will trigger an error if it actually being called.