# Blender's issue: No module multiarray found in numpy.core module [Python3.7]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, blender

Versions: OS Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, Blender 2.92, Default Python version of machine 3.7.6 Anaconda, Blender's python interpreter 3.7.7, BlenderGIS 2.2.8/2.2.5

First of all I want to install an add-ons in Blender, the so called "BlenderGIS".
Like many users before me I'm exposed to the issue of `numpy` package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in
from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/blender/2.92/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
mod = import(module_name)
#... and so on...
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try git clean -xdf (removes all
files not under version control). Otherwise reinstall numpy.
Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

I tested 2 main approaches:

- While numpy was clearly installed, I unistalled it `pip uninstall numpy` and installed again the 1.19.3 version as adviced by [Dope and others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65155403/10314460)  `pip install numpy==1.19.3`. Even `python3.7 -m pip install numpy imageio` as shown by [eudoxos](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/225#issuecomment-571076269)
- To try different versions of BlenderGIS: 2.2.5 (numpy import issue), 2.2.7 (not adapted to my blender version that is too old), 2.2.8 (numpy import issue).

Both did not work.

Now I remarked something in the blender's python console. The version used is not the same as my default python interpreter:

Default python in my machine:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> #no problem
```

Blender's python interpreter:

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:16:38)  [GCC 7.5.0]

Builtin Modules:       bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports:   from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
```

numpy is clearly present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Making a search of "multi" in the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy` folder gives those few files: [Name | Place]

- multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | core
- multiarray_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so |core
- test_multiarray.py | core/tests
- test_multiarray.py | matrixlib/tests
- test_multiarray.cpython-36.pyc | core/tests/**pycache**
- test_multiarray.cpython-36.pyc | matrixlib/tests/**pycache**
- multiarray_api.txt | core/include/numpy
- __multiarray_api.h | core/include/numpy

This is not very clear for me why blender use a different python interpreter and moreover the absence of clear possibilty to change it maybe because modules like `bpy`, `bpy.data` and so on [are very specific to blender](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/#application-modules)

The last thing I did not try is the [PYTHONPATH](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/225#issuecomment-571076269) because I prefer advices on it instead of making more mess as told by [sardathrion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248150/10314460) "However, do not mess with PYTHONPATH. More often than not, you are doing it wrong and it will only bring you trouble in the long run. For example, virtual environments could do strange things… "

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ echo $PYHTONPATH

(base) avy@machine:~$ which python
/home/avy/anaconda3/bin/python
```

---

The BlenderGIS 228's script:
"/home/avy/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-228/**init**.py"

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

#  ***** GPL LICENSE BLOCK *****
#
#  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#  All rights reserved.
#  ***** GPL LICENSE BLOCK *****

import bpy

bl_info = {
    'name': 'BlenderGIS',
    'description': 'Various tools for handle geodata',
    'author': 'domlysz',
    'license': 'GPL',
    'deps': '',
    'version': (2, 2, 8),
    'blender': (2, 83, 0),
    'location': 'View3D > Tools > GIS',
    'warning': '',
    'wiki_url': 'https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki',
    'tracker_url': 'https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues',
    'link': '',
    'support': 'COMMUNITY',
    'category': '3D View'
    }

class BlenderVersionError(Exception):
    pass

if bl_info['blender'] > bpy.app.version:
    raise BlenderVersionError(f"This addon requires Blender >= {bl_info['blender']}")

#Modules
CAM_GEOPHOTO = True
CAM_GEOREF = True
EXPORT_SHP = True
GET_DEM = True
IMPORT_GEORASTER = True
IMPORT_OSM = True
IMPORT_SHP = True
IMPORT_ASC = True
DELAUNAY = True
TERRAIN_NODES = True
TERRAIN_RECLASS = True
BASEMAPS = True
DROP = True
EARTH_SPHERE = True

import os, sys, tempfile
from datetime import datetime

def getAppData():
    home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    loc = os.path.join(home, '.bgis')
    if not os.path.exists(loc):
        os.mkdir(loc)
    return loc

APP_DATA = getAppData()

import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
#temporary set log level, will be overriden reading addon prefs
#logsFormat = "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s"
logsFormat = '{levelname}:{name}:{lineno}:{message}'
logsFileName = 'bgis.log'
try:
    #logsFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), logsFileName)
    logsFilePath = os.path.join(APP_DATA, logsFileName)
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.getLevelName('DEBUG'), format=logsFormat, style='{', filename=logsFilePath, filemode='w')
    logHandler = RotatingFileHandler(logsFilePath, mode='a', maxBytes=512000, backupCount=1)
except PermissionError:
    #logsFilePath = os.path.join(bpy.app.tempdir, logsFileName)
    logsFilePath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), logsFileName)
    logHandler = RotatingFileHandler(logsFilePath, mode='a', maxBytes=512000, backupCount=1)
logHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logsFormat, style='{'))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('###### Starting new Blender session : {}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

def _excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    if 'BlenderGIS' in exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename:
        logger.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
    sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

sys.excepthook = _excepthook #warn, this is a global variable, can be overrided by another addon

####
'''
Workaround for `sys.excepthook` thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643327/sys-excepthook-and-threading
'''
import threading

init_original = threading.Thread.__init__

def init(self, *args, **kwargs):

    init_original(self, *args, **kwargs)
    run_original = self.run

    def run_with_except_hook(*args2, **kwargs2):
        try:
            run_original(*args2, **kwargs2)
        except Exception:
            sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())

    self.run = run_with_except_hook

threading.Thread.__init__ = init

####


import ssl
if (not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and
    getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None)):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

#from .core.checkdeps import HAS_GDAL, HAS_PYPROJ, HAS_PIL, HAS_IMGIO
from .core.settings import settings

#Import all modules which contains classes that must be registed (classes derived from bpy.types.*)
from . import prefs
from . import geoscene

if CAM_GEOPHOTO:
    from .operators import add_camera_exif
if CAM_GEOREF:
    from .operators import add_camera_georef
if EXPORT_SHP:
    from .operators import io_export_shp
if GET_DEM:
    from .operators import io_get_dem
if IMPORT_GEORASTER:
    from .operators import io_import_georaster
if IMPORT_OSM:
    from .operators import io_import_osm
if IMPORT_SHP:
    from .operators import io_import_shp
if IMPORT_ASC:
    from .operators import io_import_asc
if DELAUNAY:
    from .operators import mesh_delaunay_voronoi
if TERRAIN_NODES:
    from .operators import nodes_terrain_analysis_builder
if TERRAIN_RECLASS:
    from .operators import nodes_terrain_analysis_reclassify
if BASEMAPS:
    from .operators import view3d_mapviewer
if DROP:
    from .operators import object_drop
if EARTH_SPHERE:
    from .operators import mesh_earth_sphere


import bpy.utils.previews as iconsLib
icons_dict = {}


class BGIS_OT_logs(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "bgis.logs"
    bl_description = 'Display BlenderGIS logs'
    bl_label = "Logs"

    def execute(self, context):
        if logsFileName in bpy.data.texts:
            logs = bpy.data.texts[logsFileName]
        else:
            logs = bpy.data.texts.load(logsFilePath)
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.5)
        area = bpy.context.area
        area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
        area.spaces[0].text = logs
        bpy.ops.text.reload()
        return {'FINISHED'}


class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_import(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Import"
    def draw(self, context):
        if IMPORT_SHP:
            self.layout.operator("importgis.shapefile_file_dialog", icon_value=icons_dict["shp"].icon_id, text='Shapefile (.shp)')
        if IMPORT_GEORASTER:
            self.layout.operator("importgis.georaster", icon_value=icons_dict["raster"].icon_id, text="Georeferenced raster (.tif .jpg .jp2 .png)")
        if IMPORT_OSM:
            self.layout.operator("importgis.osm_file", icon_value=icons_dict["osm"].icon_id, text="Open Street Map xml (.osm)")
        if IMPORT_ASC:
            self.layout.operator('importgis.asc_file', icon_value=icons_dict["asc"].icon_id, text="ESRI ASCII Grid (.asc)")

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_export(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Export"
    def draw(self, context):
        if EXPORT_SHP:
            self.layout.operator('exportgis.shapefile', text="Shapefile (.shp)", icon_value=icons_dict["shp"].icon_id)

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_webgeodata(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Web geodata"
    def draw(self, context):
        if BASEMAPS:
            self.layout.operator("view3d.map_start", icon_value=icons_dict["layers"].icon_id)
        if IMPORT_OSM:
            self.layout.operator("importgis.osm_query", icon_value=icons_dict["osm"].icon_id)
        if GET_DEM:
            self.layout.operator("importgis.dem_query", icon_value=icons_dict["raster"].icon_id)

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_camera(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Camera"
    def draw(self, context):
        if CAM_GEOREF:
            self.layout.operator("camera.georender", icon_value=icons_dict["georefCam"].icon_id, text='Georender')
        if CAM_GEOPHOTO:
            self.layout.operator("camera.geophotos", icon_value=icons_dict["exifCam"].icon_id, text='Geophotos')
            self.layout.operator("camera.geophotos_setactive", icon='FILE_REFRESH')

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_mesh(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Mesh"
    def draw(self, context):
        if DELAUNAY:
            self.layout.operator("tesselation.delaunay", icon_value=icons_dict["delaunay"].icon_id, text='Delaunay')
            self.layout.operator("tesselation.voronoi", icon_value=icons_dict["voronoi"].icon_id, text='Voronoi')
        if EARTH_SPHERE:
            self.layout.operator("earth.sphere", icon="WORLD", text='lonlat to sphere')
            #self.layout.operator("earth.curvature", icon="SPHERECURVE", text='Earth curvature correction')
            self.layout.operator("earth.curvature", icon_value=icons_dict["curve"].icon_id, text='Earth curvature correction')

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_object(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Object"
    def draw(self, context):
        if DROP:
            self.layout.operator("object.drop", icon_value=icons_dict["drop"].icon_id, text='Drop')

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_nodes(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Nodes"
    def draw(self, context):
        if TERRAIN_NODES:
            self.layout.operator("analysis.nodes", icon_value=icons_dict["terrain"].icon_id, text='Terrain analysis')

class VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "GIS"
    # Set the menu operators and draw functions
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("bgis.pref_show", icon='PREFERENCES')
        layout.separator()
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_webgeodata', icon="URL")
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_import', icon='IMPORT')
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_export', icon='EXPORT')
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_camera', icon='CAMERA_DATA')
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_mesh', icon='MESH_DATA')
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_object', icon='CUBE')
        layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_nodes', icon='NODETREE')
        layout.separator()
        layout.operator("bgis.logs", icon='TEXT')

menus = [
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_webgeodata,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_import,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_export,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_camera,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_mesh,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_object,
VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis_nodes
]


def add_gis_menu(self, context):
    if context.mode == 'OBJECT':
        self.layout.menu('VIEW3D_MT_menu_gis')


def register():
    #icons
    global icons_dict
    icons_dict = iconsLib.new()
    icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")
    for icon in os.listdir(icons_dir):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(icon)
        icons_dict.load(name, os.path.join(icons_dir, icon), 'IMAGE')

    #operators
    prefs.register()
    geoscene.register()

    for menu in menus:
        try:
            bpy.utils.register_class(menu)
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.warning('{} is already registered, now unregister and retry... '.format(menu))
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(menu)
            bpy.utils.register_class(menu)

    bpy.utils.register_class(BGIS_OT_logs)

    if BASEMAPS:
        view3d_mapviewer.register()
    if IMPORT_GEORASTER:
        io_import_georaster.register()
    if IMPORT_SHP:
        io_import_shp.register()
    if EXPORT_SHP:
        io_export_shp.register()
    if IMPORT_OSM:
        io_import_osm.register()
    if IMPORT_ASC:
        io_import_asc.register()
    if DELAUNAY:
        mesh_delaunay_voronoi.register()
    if DROP:
        object_drop.register()
    if GET_DEM:
        io_get_dem.register()
    if CAM_GEOPHOTO:
        add_camera_exif.register()
    if CAM_GEOREF:
        add_camera_georef.register()
    if TERRAIN_NODES:
        nodes_terrain_analysis_builder.register()
    if TERRAIN_RECLASS:
        nodes_terrain_analysis_reclassify.register()
    if EARTH_SPHERE:
        mesh_earth_sphere.register()

    #menus
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.append(add_gis_menu)

    #shortcuts
    if not bpy.app.background: #no ui when running as background
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        kc =  wm.keyconfigs.active
        if '3D View' in kc.keymaps:
            km = kc.keymaps['3D View']
            if BASEMAPS:
                kmi = km.keymap_items.new(idname='view3d.map_start', type='NUMPAD_ASTERIX', value='PRESS')

    #Setup prefs
    preferences = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences
    logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(preferences.logLevel)) #will affect all child logger

    #update core settings according to addon prefs
    settings.proj_engine = preferences.projEngine
    settings.img_engine = preferences.imgEngine


def unregister():

    global icons_dict
    iconsLib.remove(icons_dict)

    if not bpy.app.background: #no ui when running as background
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        if '3D View' in  wm.keyconfigs.active.keymaps:
            km = wm.keyconfigs.active.keymaps['3D View']
            if BASEMAPS:
                if 'view3d.map_start' in km.keymap_items:
                    kmi = km.keymap_items.remove(km.keymap_items['view3d.map_start'])

    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.remove(add_gis_menu)

    for menu in menus:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(menu)

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BGIS_OT_logs)

    prefs.unregister()
    geoscene.unregister()
    if BASEMAPS:
        view3d_mapviewer.unregister()
    if IMPORT_GEORASTER:
        io_import_georaster.unregister()
    if IMPORT_SHP:
        io_import_shp.unregister()
    if EXPORT_SHP:
        io_export_shp.unregister()
    if IMPORT_OSM:
        io_import_osm.unregister()
    if IMPORT_ASC:
        io_import_asc.unregister()
    if DELAUNAY:
        mesh_delaunay_voronoi.unregister()
    if DROP:
        object_drop.unregister()
    if GET_DEM:
        io_get_dem.unregister()
    if CAM_GEOPHOTO:
        add_camera_exif.unregister()
    if CAM_GEOREF:
        add_camera_georef.unregister()
    if TERRAIN_NODES:
        nodes_terrain_analysis_builder.unregister()
    if TERRAIN_RECLASS:
        nodes_terrain_analysis_reclassify.unregister()
    if EARTH_SPHERE:
        mesh_earth_sphere.unregister()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Numpy.core's init:
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_*init*_.py"

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function

from .info import __doc__
from numpy.version import version as __version__

# disables OpenBLAS affinity setting of the main thread that limits
# python threads or processes to one core
import os
env_added = []
for envkey in ['OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE', 'GOTOBLAS_MAIN_FREE']:
    if envkey not in os.environ:
        os.environ[envkey] = '1'
        env_added.append(envkey)

try:
    from . import multiarray
except ImportError as exc:
    msg = """
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: %s
""" % (exc,)
    raise ImportError(msg)

for envkey in env_added:
    del os.environ[envkey]
del envkey
del env_added
del os

from . import umath
from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
from . import numerictypes as nt
multiarray.set_typeDict(nt.sctypeDict)
from . import numeric
from .numeric import *
from . import fromnumeric
from .fromnumeric import *
from . import defchararray as char
from . import records as rec
from .records import *
from .memmap import *
from .defchararray import chararray
from . import function_base
from .function_base import *
from . import machar
from .machar import *
from . import getlimits
from .getlimits import *
from . import shape_base
from .shape_base import *
from . import einsumfunc
from .einsumfunc import *
del nt

from .fromnumeric import amax as max, amin as min, round_ as round
from .numeric import absolute as abs

__all__ = ['char', 'rec', 'memmap']
__all__ += numeric.__all__
__all__ += fromnumeric.__all__
__all__ += rec.__all__
__all__ += ['chararray']
__all__ += function_base.__all__
__all__ += machar.__all__
__all__ += getlimits.__all__
__all__ += shape_base.__all__
__all__ += einsumfunc.__all__


from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
test = _numpy_tester().test
bench = _numpy_tester().bench

# Make it possible so that ufuncs can be pickled
#  Here are the loading and unloading functions
# The name numpy.core._ufunc_reconstruct must be
#   available for unpickling to work.
def _ufunc_reconstruct(module, name):
    # The `fromlist` kwarg is required to ensure that `mod` points to the
    # inner-most module rather than the parent package when module name is
    # nested. This makes it possible to pickle non-toplevel ufuncs such as
    # scipy.special.expit for instance.
    mod = __import__(module, fromlist=[name])
    return getattr(mod, name)

def _ufunc_reduce(func):
    from pickle import whichmodule
    name = func.__name__
    return _ufunc_reconstruct, (whichmodule(func, name), name)


import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import copyreg
else:
    import copy_reg as copyreg

copyreg.pickle(ufunc, _ufunc_reduce, _ufunc_reconstruct)
# Unclutter namespace (must keep _ufunc_reconstruct for unpickling)
del copyreg
del sys
del _ufunc_reduce
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue - thanks for the detailed question.  Sorry it hasn't been answered.  Did you find a solution?  If I figure it out, I'll post my answer here.

Comment: @ChefTech No, I did not find solution about it.I dropped the process itself.

Comment: @ChefTech Just in case, I just found there are programs that manages a register of interpreters [`binfmt_misc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc), [`binfmt-support`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/binfmt-support). So, even if I didn't find a solution, I hope it can help you to know a direction to solve this python's interpreters issue.